# How to send a message Activity to Thread class

Tags: android, multithreading, message, android-handler

This is my problem. In my android application I have a process which is execute by the Thread class. During this process I need to send a message to the user to get confirm he needs to do it further. In my Thread class I have only Service instance and don't have an activity instance. So I used separate dialog activity to display a AlertDialog to the user. Now I need to get the answer that the user chose in this dialog activity box.

I know  we can use Messages and Handlers for sending messages between thread class to Activity. But my problem is different than that.

Is there any way to get the user answer to thread class or else is there any way to display a message box to user inside the thread class rather that using dialogActivity ?

Do you have any other suggestion to solve this issue? Any clue or help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think your looking at [`Thread` `wait` and `notify`](http://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example)

Comment: The message send from a activity to a thread class or else do you have any good way other that this?

Comment: use `eventbus` library!!